# Cumulative average by group

Tags: r

I want to compute trailing mean GPA by Name from the table below at each index. 
For example at index 9, I want to have the mean GPA for C from indices 3, 6, 9 and likewise for A and B. At index 6 I want to have the GPA for C from indices 3 and 6. tapply alone won't solve my problem because I want a value for each row.

What's a clean way of doing this ?

```
Index Name GPA
1     A    5
2     B    6
3     C    7
4     A    5
5     B    6
6     C    6
7     A    7
8     B    6
9     C    3
```

Comment: I wish my GPA was that high

Comment: Are you just looking for `tapply(dat$GPA, INDEX = dat$Name, FUN = mean)`? (Assuming your data is stored in `dat`).

Comment: At index 6 I want to have mean GPA from C from indices 3 and 6. At each index for each Name I want a new trailing mean.

Comment: So you basically want a cumulative mean by group?

Answer (score 3):

[Minimally reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610):

```
g <- data.frame(Name=rep(c("A","B","C"),3),
                GPA=c(5,6,7,5,6,6,7,6,3))
```

For a cumulative average, I would just use `cumsum()` and `seq_along()` restricted to rows with the same Name.

```
for(i in unique(g$Name)){
  gpa <- g$GPA[g$Name==i]
  g$cum_avg[g$Name==i] <- cumsum(gpa)/seq_along(gpa)
}
g
```

Produces:

```
  Name GPA  cum_avg
1    A   5 5.000000
2    B   6 6.000000
3    C   7 7.000000
4    A   5 5.000000
5    B   6 6.000000
6    C   6 6.500000
7    A   7 5.666667
8    B   6 6.000000
9    C   3 5.333333
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`:

```
g <- data.frame(Name=rep(c("A","B","C"),3),
            GPA=c(5,6,7,5,6,6,7,6,3))

g %>%
group_by(Name) %>%
mutate(cumu = lag(cummean(GPA), n = 0))
```

Output:

```
Source: local data frame [9 x 3]
Groups: Name [3]

Name   GPA     cumu
<fctr> <dbl>    <dbl>
1      A     5 5.000000
2      B     6 6.000000
3      C     7 7.000000
4      A     5 5.000000 
5      B     6 6.000000
6      C     6 6.500000
7      A     7 5.666667
8      B     6 6.000000
9      C     3 5.333333
```